# Jpgraph library not showing graphs after upgrade to php 7

Tags: php

I used to work with the php library jpgraph for displaying Charts on pdf files, but after uprgrading to php 7, graphs are not shown anymore with an error message. Appreciate your help.
The library: https://jpgraph.net/

Version: 3.5

Php version: 7.2

Comment: please consider adding minimal reproducible code and error message

Comment: The code is confidential and cannot share it, and this is a library issue and not in my code. Anyway I got the response and it’s working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar issue before and after a long search I found the fix in a google group which i can't remember, but with a quick search in my code here is the fix:

Replace this line:

```
if ($majorC != $majorR) return false;
```

By:

```
if ($majorC > $majorR) return true;
```

in `CheckPHPVersion` function in `jpgraph.php` file from the library.

Comment: Is it available in newer versions?